# Apache POI - Read UserProperties added in a OutlookMessage

Tags: java, outlook, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI and having problem to find out if it´s possible to read an UserProperties which is added to an Outlook-message (.msg) using VBA. I know it can be found by using VBA (eg `msg.Userproperties("outlookid")`), but I want to use Apache POI instead if it´s possible.I have tried to read `Chunks`, `CustomProperties`, `DocumentSummaryInformation`, `OutlookTextExtractor` etc, etc... If I open the msg-file in an text-editor and search for an given propertyname - I find it so I know it´s there. Is there any way to read Userproperties in Apache POI - please help!

Comment: If you run `org.apache.poi.hsmf.dev.HSMFDump` on the file, do you see the info in any of the sections that finds?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I have tried your suggestion but I can not get it to work all the way. From HSMFDump I get an NullpointerException. I do not know what causing it. It runs and printing som info but then a NullpointerException. Any clue?

Comment: Raise a bug in Apache POI, include the full stacktrace when you get the NPE, and ideally also upload a sample file. I'll then take a look and fix that NPE

Comment: Thx for your reply. I noticed that I was using an older version of POI, version 3.9. I switched to the new stable one and got it to work :) But when I look at the textfile that was created, I can not see the Userproperties key (eg "outlookid") just the value....?

`32823 - (unknown) - ASCII String
       **C1258336002C30DD_2008042B3B6**
   32820 - (unknown) - ASCII String
       [185.80.219.4]
   32821 - (unknown) - ASCII String
       8740`
What can I do?

Comment: Raise an enhancement request in the Apache POI bugzilla, upload a small sample file, and I'll try to take a look in on the weekend!

Comment: A request has been submitted, thanks for your kind support!